# What's the best way to reset deeply nested collections?

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following data structure:

One ModelA has a nested collection of ModelBs.

Each ModelB has a nested collection of ModelCs

By overriding ModelA's parse method, I can easily bootstrap the attributes for ModelA and populate the nested collection of ModelBs :

assuming the server sends { modelA_attributes: { ... }, arrayOfB_Attributes: [{..}, {..}, ..]}
I can do in the parse method: modelA.nestedBs.reset arrayOfB_Attributes and return modelA_atrributes

The problem is how can I easily reset the attributes of all ModelCs for each ModelB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [Backbone-Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational)?  It'll handle most of these.  I found a race condition doing this kind of stuff a few weeks ago, but it looks like Paul's fixed it.

Comment: Provides exactly the kind of functionalities I needed. Thanks again. :-)